# Error clicking Finish editing - XPM

Tags: experience-manager

When trying to edit content in XPM and clicking on Finish Editing, we are seeing the following error
Unable to cast object of type 'Tridion.ContentManager.CommunicationManagement.PublicationTarget' to type 'Tridion.ContentManager.CommunicationManagement.TargetType'

Recently we created a new staging publication target (we already had one staging) and removed it. We are on Tridion 2013 SP1HR1

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, the issue was with recent changes to event system code.